# Select elements with an attribute with cheerio

Tags: node.js, dom, css-selectors, cheerio

What is the most efficient way to select all dom elements that have a certain attribute.

```
<input name="mode">
```

With plain javascript I would use : `document.querySelectorAll("[name='mode']")`
or `document.querySelectorAll("[name]")` if I don't care about the attribute value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok I found it in the cheerio documentation, here is how you do it:

```
$('[name=mode]')
```

[cheerio docs: Selectors](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#-selector-context-root-)

Answer (score 11):

For some reason, the accepted answer didn't work for me (using cheerio ^1.0.0-rc.2 here).

But for the following markup:

```
<input value="123" name="data[text_amount]">
```

this did work:

```
$('input[name="data[text_amount]"]'));
```

The double quote did the magic. Got that from [cheerio's help docs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#prop-name-value-).