# Traversing HTML with Cheerio. Attempting to grab img src nested inside <a> tag

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am using cheerio to try and traverse the HTML of a website and I am trying grab the src attribute from the images but they are nested inside  tags. I have tried a few solutions one example given below but no luck. Thank you in advance. 
[image]

```js
 const snkrsproduct = $('a.card-link img');
        const snkrsImg = snkrsproduct.attr('src');
        console.log(snkrsImg);
```

It keeps returning undefined. My logic to this is that I am grabbing the a tag with a class of card-link and then the img and assigning that img src value to snkrsImg but  obviously  I am missing something.

Comment: Have you tried using a selector like 'a.card-link>img'

Comment: I'll give that try but how does that differ from "a.card-link img" ?

Comment: The > in a selector says 'is child of'. So, in this case, it says: img is child of a.card-link

Comment: const snkrsproduct = $('.card-link > img'); still comes back undefined , not sure why

Comment: Him. Yeah, I've had problems with cheerio and selecting elements. Your positive that the a has a class of 'card-link'?

Comment: Just saw the image you attached. Looks like it should work. Do any selectors work?

Comment: Next thing I would try is $('a.card-link') and see if that comes back with a collection that you can iterate. From there, you should be able to get to the child elements and grab the src attribute. If $('a.card-link') does NOT work, then cheerio might be having a problem with the fact that the a element has multiple classes on it.

Comment: Yeah I can grab the .card-link and get the data off of that such as 'href' and 'aria-label'

Comment: Yes no $('a.card-link').attr(aria-label) returns the name of the shoe , so that is working. but i dont understand why it can go one level down and grab the img hahaha

Comment: does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41198485/462121

Comment: No , that didn't work either I tried this                                                                
  const snkrimgUrl = $('img[class="image-component"]');

Comment: what about this: $('a.card-link').siblings('img')

Comment: actually, it should have been this one: $('a.card-link').children('img')

Comment: Sorry , had to go to work :/ gonna give this a shot

Comment: It sounds like it's not there. Just because it's in the inspector doesn't mean it's in the html. You might need puppeteer for this.

Comment: Yeah , fellow dev mentioned this to me. The pages are being rendered using react and possibly redux.